# When using TypeScript with WebDriverIO, do I need to use 'tsc' to compile before running my tests? or does the wdio binary compile and excute itself?

Tags: javascript, typescript, webdriver-io

I've not had much hands on experience with TypeScript until now, I've translated all my .js files into TypeScript and set up the right interfaces, yet I can't run .ts files natively with JSNode so obviously I'll have to compile it.

I've seen in the documention there is a config which is autoCompile, but when I run the wdio.conf.js against the .ts file, it doesn't run them.

What am I missing here? do I have to run 'tsc' command before I run all my tests and direct my wdio.conf.js to my /dist/ folder?

Comment: It says here you need `ts-node` to automatically compile typescript : https://webdriver.io/docs/typescript/

Comment: @Kokodoko I have ts-node installed.
    "ts-node": "^10.0.0",